# Replacing react-native-camera with react-native-vision-camera: Adding overlay images and reducing captured image size

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-camera, react-native-vision-camera

I'm currently working on a React Native project and I need to replace the **deprecated react-native-camera** library with **react-native-vision-camera**. However, I'm facing a couple of challenges in the process.

1. **Overlay Images**: With react-native-camera, I was able to add overlay
   images while capturing images. How can I achieve the same
   functionality with react-native-vision-camera? Are there any
   specific APIs or approaches I should follow?
2. **Reducing Captured Image Size**: Another requirement is to reduce the
   size of the captured image. In the previous implementation, I was
   able to control the image quality and compression settings using
   react-native-camera. How can I achieve similar control with
   react-native-vision-camera to ensure smaller file sizes for the
   captured images?

I've already reviewed the documentation and examples provided by react-native-vision-camera, but couldn't find specific guidance on these topics. Any help or code snippets would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

With expo-camera you can do both things but you have to install the expo package. In case you only need a rectangle and same words overlaying the camera image you could use react-native-image-crop-picker.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Natalia. However, I specifically need to replace react-native-camera with react-native-vision-camera and include overlay images while reducing the captured image size. The suggestion of using expo-camera or react-native-image-crop-picker doesn't address this. Can you provide insights or alternatives for achieving this with react-native-vision-camera? Thanks!